# buy now button is displaying in different positions in product view page

Tags: addtocart, product-view

please visit these links :

if tier prices are available than its displaying like this :

http://hotwheelstoys.in/totaltoys2/var/www/html/totaltoys/happy-hours-scribblez.html [ this is fine ]

if tier prices are not available, than its displaying like this :

http://hotwheelstoys.in/totaltoys2/var/www/html/totaltoys/index.php/dream-house.html [this is not fine ]

means , "BUY NOW " button is far away from "ADD TO CART"

Add to cart button is calling from addtocart.phtml [extension]

> /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/extension/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

BUY NOW button is calling from view.phtml :

> app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

i followed this to add buy now button :

http://blog.fusedwebspace.co.uk/adding-buy-now-button-to-magento-1-9-that-skips-the-shopping-cart/

Comment: post your view.phtml

Comment: please check here view.phtml = http://pastebin.com/gcUqbs91

Comment: addtocart.phtml file = > http://pastebin.com/wM35eGfQ

Comment: please use core writing code because of in future this will not going helpful for other users, thanks

Comment: sure @amit_game i will try from next time.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things.

**Step 1:**

Place your buy now button inside `<div class="add-to-box">` div.

**Step 2:**

Remove style for `buy-now` button.

```
.button.buy-now {


background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #f78828 0px, #dd771f 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
padding: 3px;
width: 184px;
position:relative;
left: -240px; 
 top : 50px; 

}
```

replace with this

```
.button.buy-now {


background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #f78828 0px, #dd771f 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
padding: 3px;
width: 184px;

}
```

I have edited the [view.phtml](http://pastebin.com/3BAdS5gn) check this.

Answer (score 2):

you "buy now" is not contained in the left box. (the one with the product price).
It is positioned below the 2 boxes.
It looks ok on the first link because the 2 boxes have about the same height.
On the second link, the box on the right is much bigger and it pushes the button down.

Comment: thanks a lot , i updated as mentioned by @Meenakshi . i will try for better  css next time